# click to change background toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on  it changes background. It works fine. But what if I want to click on it again to restore the original background? I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".select").on("click", function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/selected.png)");
    });
});
```

Here is jsfiddle [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/09xgrhxo/)

Basically when I click on the div it changes the background, which is fine. But I want to have ability to click on it again to restore the original background.
It will be an alternative solution for tick box, but just for demo purposes.

Thanks

Comment: much simpler to toggle a class that contains css rule, much easier to undo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS

replace

```
$(this).css("background-image", "url(images/selected.png)");
```

with

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

Style

```
#multiselect .active {
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/09xgrhxo/4/

Comment: Close. .toggleClass('active')

Comment: My bad, amended; toggle is used for something else I believe.

Comment: Almost. :) Your fiddle doesn't appear to work. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/09xgrhxo/3/

Comment: Your css is not correct. Simply using `.active` is not going to be specific enough to overwrite the current image

Comment: It's more than enough, check the fiddle link.

Comment: Oh, yeah no I'm with you, fixed it on here (was already fixed on the fiddle).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `.css()` to change the `background-image` I would add a class in your CSS and use `.toggleClass()`.

Also be aware that simply adding a class will not be specific enough because your css is using:

```
#multiselect .select
```

you're going to have to target the class you add as a child of `#multiselect`:

```
#multiselect .change
```

**CSS**

```
#multiselect .change{
   background-image: url(http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ51HqKXkejWAFcSBrodHd5eUN2QaIJro0jhN1YpmljSdQ5dj2)
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".select").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("change");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/09xgrhxo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data-*` attribute.

```js
$('.select').attr('data-img', $('.select').css('background-image'));
$(".select").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-image", ($(this).css('background-image') == $(this).data('img')) ? "url(http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZ51HqKXkejWAFcSBrodHd5eUN2QaIJro0jhN1YpmljSdQ5dj2)" : $(this).data('img'));
});
```

```css
#multiselect .select {
  background: url(http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQF_ErOlc78eOGZaEWb-dwPkrv2uyAoKx0Pbn3-e0tAZoUDSQRCsA) center;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiselect">
  <div class="select">Option1</div>
  <div class="select">Option2</div>
  <div class="select">Option3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try starting with c=1; I have to click twice to get it to change the first time.

Comment: Weird. Does for me too, now. Wonder what happened?

Comment: @Jackhardcastle - It's just another way of doing it.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle - Downvoting because I used a different approach, doesn't make sense to me and sounds ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing background-img url in javascrpt, I would suggest to create two classes having same properties but different background-img url which you want to toggle. so here we will be toggling class (ultimately background-img) in javascript.

see jsfiddle [example][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/09xgrhxo/13/
```